# How do i add custom fields to UserManager in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a user profile, i followed through a tutorial which has registration for only username, email and password but i want to be able to add other custom fields.

What i did:

Models.py:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None,):
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('User should have a userame')
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users should have a Email')
        
        user = self.model(username=username , email = self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('User should have a password')
       
        user=self.create_user(username,email,password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user

class User(models.Model):
    dso = models.ForeignKey(Dso,related_name='dso',default=NULL,blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    roleId = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default='1')
    isActive = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=True)
    customerId = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    
    dateJoined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=False, default=NULL)

    @property
    def energy_data(self):
        energydata = EnergyData.objects.filter(customerId=self.customerId).first()
        return energydata
```

Serializers.py:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length = 68, min_length=6, write_only = True)
    
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['email','username','password','name','address','customerId', 
                  'dso', 'roleId']
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        username = attrs.get('username', '')

        if not len(username) >= 4:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Username must be morethan 4 letters or characters')
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

Views.py:

```
class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class= RegisterSerializer 
    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        user_data = serializer.data

        user= User.objects.get(email=user_data['email'])

        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token

        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain

        relativeLink = reverse('email-verify')
        
        absolute_url = 'http://'+current_site+relativeLink+"?token="+str(token)

        email_body= 'Hi '+ user.username + ' Use this link below to verify your email \n'+ absolute_url

        data = {'email_subject': 'Verify Your Email', 'email_body': email_body , 'to_email': user.email}

        Util.send_email(data)

        return Response(user_data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

URL Path:

```
path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name="register" )
```

When i do this and try to test i get the error, '**UserManager.create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'**'

Please kindly help as i am new to django rest frameworrk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your serializers.py you have the fields list that includes the variable 'name', but it is never defined in the models.py

Try to change serializers.py

```
 fields=['email','username','password','address','customerId', 
                  'dso', 'roleId']
```

And modify the variable name in models.py to be username instead of name

```
 username = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with Django having a Model called "user" is going to create problems at some point since Django already have a User model pre-installed in the backend.

I know this is not the exact answer you were looking for, this will probably spare you a headache in the future.

To create a user profile I created the following model linking the User model with a OneToOneField.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to="images/")
    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

and obvioulsy imported

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

As a result,

1. I would remove your User model
2. Import "from django.contrib.auth.models import User"
3. add to the first line of your
   UserManager Model, I would add

   "user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: okay thanks, i would try it out... although I was able to do somethings nd bypassed the error but I am still having issues.

I would update the question with my recent changes

Comment: It's okay to have a `User` model but it needs to inherit `AbstractUser` - as pointed out by @PhilM you're going to have problems if you just create a new one